# Divide a `div` into two halves without any borders and provide the index for the dropped div in `Z` manner

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a dynamic form where there is a `ul` and an empty `div`. The user have to drag a `li` from that `ul` and drop it into that empty div. Right now I've done like, the empty div is divided into two halves. The user can drop into both. The dropped `div` is sortable. The sorting can be done between those divs too. This is how I've tried:

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
  $(document).on('mousedown mouseup', '.grabbing, .grab', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('grabbing').toggleClass('grab');
  });

  $('.side_bar_element').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".wrapper",            
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.55,
    zIndex: 100,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      cursor: "grabbing"
    }
  });

  $(".wrapper").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      cursor: "grabbing"        
      console.log("Start position: " + ui.item.startPos);
      console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

```css
ul.side_bar li{
  list-style: none; 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #53D4F3;
}

#right-box .preview, #left-box .content {
  display: none;
}
#right-box .content, #left-box .preview {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper{
  min-height: 400px;                   
  background-color: rgba(154, 210, 148, 1);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  column-count: 3;

}
.grab {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.grabbing {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

.content{
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#left{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  height: 300px;
}
#right{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></scrip‌​t>

</script>
    <ul class="side_bar">
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 1 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 2 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 3 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>Please drag the elements to this box<br>
    <!-- the right box wrapper for dropped elements-->
    <div id="right-box wrapper">
      <div id="left" class="wrapper connectedSortable" style="float:left; width: 50%">
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="wrapper connectedSortable" style="float:right; width: 50%">
      </div>
    </div>
```

No this is how it looks like:
[image]

Now, each div has a dynamically created `div`. The dropped divs inside the left div has indexes 0, 1, 2 and the dropped divs inside the left div has indexes 0 and 1. For me, how I want is, the dropped divs on both the sides should have the index continuously like, 0, 1, 2, 3.. in `Z` type. Like,

```
This is how it is now:
___________________________________

(main div)
 | div1(index-0) | div2(index-0) |
 | div1(index-1) | div2(index-1) |
 | div1(index-2) | div2(index-2) |
 | div1(index-2) | div2(index-3) |
___________________________________

This is how I want.


   ___________________________________
    (main div)
    | div1(index-0) | div2(index-1) |
    | div1(index-2) | div2(index-3) |
    | div1(index-4) | div2(index-5) |
    | div1(index-6) | div2(index-7) |
    ___________________________________
```

How can I do that? Is there a way?

Comment: Console message: ".draggable is not a function". And this statement is some strange: "The dropped divs inside the _left_ div has indexes 0, 1, 2 and the dropped divs inside the _left_ div has indexes 0 and 1." Pls, review your post.

Comment: You need to add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` to the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Please Include Latest Jquery And Jquery Ui For Your Code..

Use This Two Links Instead Pervious Library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

See the solution Of Your Problem in snippest.

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
  $(document).on('mousedown mouseup', '.grabbing, .grab', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('grabbing').toggleClass('grab');
  });

  $('.side_bar_element').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".wrapper",            
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.55,
    zIndex: 100,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      cursor: "grabbing"
    }
  });

  $(".wrapper").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      cursor: "grabbing"        
      console.log("Start position: " + ui.item.startPos);
      console.log("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    }
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

```css
ul.side_bar li{
  list-style: none; 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #53D4F3;
}

#right-box .preview, #left-box .content {
  display: none;
}
#right-box .content, #left-box .preview {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper{
  min-height: 400px;                   
  background-color: rgba(154, 210, 148, 1);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  column-count: 3;

}
.grab {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.grabbing {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

.content{
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#left{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  height: 300px;
}
#right{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul class="side_bar">
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 1 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 2 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
      <li id="left-box" class="side_bar_element grab">
        <div class="preview">Item 3 (drag me)</div>
        <div class="content"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 20px;"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>Please drag the elements to this box<br>
    <!-- the right box wrapper for dropped elements-->
    <div id="right-box wrapper">
      <div id="left" class="wrapper connectedSortable" style="float:left; width: 50%">
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="wrapper connectedSortable" style="float:right; width: 50%">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Note :** Please Include First Jquery and Then Jquery Ui.